# Are multiple examples 'ones'?

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct in terms of English grammar to say “ones” in this sentence:

“Traffic problems and pollution are *ones* of the main threats to the 21st century.”?

Comment: ...are among the main threats of the 21st century.

Comment: ...English grammar

Comment: No, it's not.  If you're grouping traffic problems and pollution into a singular item, which I don't see how, but if you are, then you would say "*one* of the main threats."  If you are not grouping them together, since they are two things, you would say "*two* of the main threats."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One for a single item (singular verb) and some (plural verb) for multiple items.

> Pollution **is one** of the main threats **of** the 21st century.
>
> Traffic problems and pollution **are some** of the main threats **of**
>   the 21st century.